# Targeting rowIndex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to target specific rows within a table on a user's click. Right now, I have the following code:

```
function getRowIndex(x) {
    console.log("Row " + x.rowIndex + " was clicked.");
}

document.getElementsByTagName("tr").onclick = function () {
        getRowIndex(this);
};
```

Nothing happens. I've fought with this a ton , and even seen some stuff on here and elsewhere that seemed like it should work, but either I get errors because it fires onload instead of onclick, or when I fix that nothing happens at all.

Ultimately, I'm trying to target the rowIndex in order to retrieve that row's id, to then retrieve some JSON data via that id.

No jquery please. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to add the `onclick ` event to all rows in a loop, you cannot assign it with the selector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `onclick` event to all rows in a loop, you cannot assign it with a `getElements` selector:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
     rows[i].onclick = function () { getRowIndex(rows[i]); };
}
```

Comment: For whatever reason, this isn't working. for testing purposes I removed the function literal, and it fires onload as I would expect, but as soon as I wrap it in the function literal again, nothing happens onclick.

Comment: @Jeronimo Are you getting an error? What exactly is not working?

Comment: What does `document.getElementsByTagName("tr").length` show you?

Comment: it gets me the # of rows (51 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to set `onclick` on an HTML collection. The DOM doesn't work that way (jQuery does, but you've said you're not using it). The DOM is very element-oriented, not set-based.

You could hook the event on every row, but instead, I'd hook it on the `table` or `tbody` those rows are in, since the click will bubble to it. Then I'd act on the click if it came through a row:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    while (element && element != this) {
        if (element.tagName === "TR") {
            getRowIndex(element);
            return;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
function getRowIndex(element) {
    console.log("rowIndex = " + element.rowIndex);
}
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    while (element && element != this) {
        if (element.tagName === "TR") {
            getRowIndex(element);
            return;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```